# Como verificar se os campos estão vazios antes de adicionar no arraylist?

Tags: java, swing

estou com uma dúvida: como eu poderia verificar se os campos dos meus JTextFields estão vazios antes de adicionar no arraylist?, como ficaria a validação nesta parte de código?

```
                Endereco enderecoPJ=new Endereco();
                PessoaJuridica pessoaJuridica=new PessoaJuridica();


                pessoaJuridica.setNome(tfNome.getText());
                pessoaJuridica.setSobrenome(tfSobrenome.getText());
                pessoaJuridica.setCnpj((Long.valueOf(tfIndentificador.getText())));


                enderecoPJ.setBairro(tfBairro.getText());
                enderecoPJ.setCep(Long.valueOf(tfCep.getText()));
                enderecoPJ.setCidade((String)cbCidades.getSelectedItem());
                enderecoPJ.setNum(Integer.valueOf(tfNum.getText()));
                enderecoPJ.setRua(tfRua.getText());

                pessoaControler.pj.add(pessoaJuridica);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadastrado com Sucesso !");
```

Comment: Creio que a resposta dessa pergunta marcada como duplicata seja a solução. Em resumo basta aplicar `trim()` e depois validar num if com `isEmpty()`

Comment: Creio que pergunta marcada como duplicata não seja muito aplicável no meu código, eu quero verificar todos os campos, depois que verificar, se algum campo tiver vazio não poderei adicionar no arraylist, caso contrário ele adicione

Comment: A logica aplicada nas duas respostas é exatamente essa. Em uma delas eu fiz até um portugol sobre como validar isso.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar um método para verificar isso.

Nele você vai passsar como parâmetro o seu JTextFields e verificar se está vazio ou não.

Aí você precisa fazer um if pra cada JTextFields que você deseja adicionar no array.

É uma lógica bem simples, se tiver dúvidas de como fazer pode comentar aqui que a gente tenta ajudar.

Boa sorte!